# How can I change the font of Android ContextMenu?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I dont think my question needs much explanation, I just need to change the font and its size of my Context menu items. How do I do that?

here is my Code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
      super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.listmenu, menu);

    }
```

This is how I get the default contextmenu for android. But I want to customize it.

Comment: how are you creating the context menu?

Answer (score 2):

Could you create your own layout to inflate instead of R.menu.listmenu, and then set a custom font on that?

Alternatively you could try to intercept the user touch and pop up an entirely custom menu, but this might be jarring to the user who is expecting a certain font/menu.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (name .equalsIgnoreCase(“com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView”)) {
            try{
                LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();
                final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs);
                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // set the background drawable
                        view .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_ac_menu_background);

                        // set the text color
                        ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                });
                return view;
            } catch (InflateException e) {
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
        }
        return null;
    }
});
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested and work like charm :)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_feedback_filter, menu);

    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        MenuItem mi = menu.getItem(i);
        //for aapplying a font to subMenu ...
        SubMenu subMenu = mi.getSubMenu();
        if (subMenu != null && subMenu.size() > 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < subMenu.size(); j++) {
                MenuItem subMenuItem = subMenu.getItem(j);
                applyFontToMenuItem(subMenuItem, typeface);
            }
        }
        //the method we have create in activity
        applyFontToMenuItem(mi, typeface);
    }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}



private void applyFontToMenuItem(MenuItem mi, Typeface font) {
    SpannableString mNewTitle = new SpannableString(mi.getTitle());
    mNewTitle.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), 0, mNewTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    mi.setTitle(mNewTitle);
}
```

Custom span class

```
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.TypefaceSpan;

public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

    private final Typeface newType;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
        super(family);
        newType = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
    }

    private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
        int oldStyle;
        Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
        if (old == null) {
            oldStyle = 0;
        } else {
            oldStyle = old.getStyle();
        }

        int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
        if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        }

        if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
        }

        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```